# How to print message in an Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Hi I'm starting to learn how to write Android Apps for the first time but I'm running into problems.

When I go to the string.xml file to enter a message to be printed on the screen. Instead of printing my message it prints "Hello World." It should also be noted that I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1#comments

And in their tutorial there is a statement that says to change a hello world string to my own custom message. Problem is when I opened the file there was no hello world string. (But the app prints hello world anyway.) And when I go out of my way to make a hello world statement per the example.

Before I modified the file:

```
  <resources>
   <string name="app_name">OMG Android</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
 </resources>
```

After I modified the file:

```
 <resources>
   <string name="app_name">OMG Android</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="Hello_World">Dpolaristar is programming in Android</string>
 </resources>
```

The app prints Hello World without the personal message anyway. I'm confused, can anyone tell me if there is some sort of automatic override or somewhere else in the project where it says give the ability to print Hello World that I can override. I already looked but I can't find anything.

My problem also seems to be oddly specific which makes me think I either touched something I shouldn't have or maybe I'm using a different version of Android Studios then the author of the tutorial.

Help?

EDIT:

I managed to get to the text view of the activity_main.xml to add the reference. Problem is there is no textview section to add under.

Here is a copy and paste of the file which I DID NOT change for reference:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton  android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT 2:I've looked around my project and have found that in the DESIGN view of the content_main.xml I does show the value for the string I typed just not when I run the app ON MY TABLET!

Does this give anyone any clues?

Comment: Post your strings.xml here.

Comment: How when I try to copy and paste the code it removes the formatting and just appears as plain text....It's more or less identical to what the link I showed does in the example about near the bottom......

Comment: When you are editing your answer you can see formatting options there, use them, or just post the code, i will edit it.

Comment: You're saying there was no line `<string name="hello_world">Hello World</string>` in the `strings.xml` file? There are only two other places that string would be, but if you followed this example, that line should be there.

Comment: Post the `TextView` where you are setting this `Hello_World`

Comment: @cricket_007 That is exactly what I'm saying. Code should be there but it isn't and just to be safe I removed the code and ran it again and still get hello world.

Comment: @dpolaristar Hi, look at my answer and preferently do a refresh -> Build, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the property name must be "`hello_world`", don´t use capital characters, it will cause problems in your proyect!

```
<string name="hello_world">Darryl is learning Android!</string>
```

Then just add the reference:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

Then you will see the sentence `Darryl is learning Android!` displayed in your `TextView`.

The value `<string name="hello_world">Darryl is learning Android!</string>`
must be setted inside **/res/values/strings.xml**

To open the layout that contains the `TextView` go to **/res/layout/activity_main.xml** or **/res/layout/activity_my.xml** like in your example.

Comment: Add the reference where? (I'm very green when it comes to Android.)

Comment: Oops! I think you´re as green as Hulk!  I mean the reference of the string to the TextView:  android:text="@string/hello_world" =) , btw i think this is a better "Hello Wordl" tutorial  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm

Comment: No I got what you want me to enter I was wondering what file to enter that info in my project.

I meant more greenhorn....as in noob.

Comment: I put it in my answer : The value <string name="hello_world">Darryl is learning Android!</string> must be setted inside /res/values/strings.xml

Comment: But it IS settled there......it was settled there before I asked the question.
I was wondering where to put the reference.

         android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

Comment: In the `TextView` of your layout. She has mentioned that in the answer too! The layout exists in the **/res/layout/activity_my.xml**

Comment: got it,  go to your MainActivity  inside the onCreate() method click the line R.layout.activity_main then you can see the layout where a TextView is contained =)

Comment: or go to /res/layout/activity_main.xml,

Answer (score 3):

Based on the tutorial you were following it appears as if you are generating just a blank layout resource file which by default populates with the static value of "Hello World". In order to manipulate this value with the String resource you created you will need to adjust the Layout file where the Textview is being stored.

[image]

Now based on your code you would need to edit the **android:text** section of your Layout file. I generated a string very similar to yours however I edited the resource file above to set the text properly. Now you can see the value updated with the custom string I implemented.

[image]

[image]

Any time you are referencing a String resource from your Strings.xml file you will use the syntax: **android:text="@string/STRINGNAME"**. This tells the IDE you are pulling the string from your Strings.xml resource file and that you don't want the exact text you are inputting.

**EDIT**

Ok with the addition of your Layout XML you clarified a bunch :) I can see you generated a Blank activity which is configured using a Coordinator Layout. A secondary layout should have been auto-generated with that labeled **content_main.xml**. This is where you need to look for your TextView. You are looking at the main layout but not the container found within the unit.

[image]

Comment: But I am in the Strings.xml resource file and I do not recognize any of the code in my project.

Comment: Your instructions are very good...but I must have a different version or set-up of Android studios then you because I only get the screen with a tablet but not the actual code when I open up that file. (Basically a slightly altered version of the preview screen.) So either the place where I add that has been moved or I need to find a way to access that screen in the activity_main.xml.

Comment: are you using Eclipse or Android studio?

Comment: @dpolaristar - It is very small, but towards the bottom of the preview screen there are 2 tabs that say Design and Text. I think you want to click the Text one.

Comment: @cricket_007 I managed to find the screen your referring to...problem is it looks different there is no <TextView.....

Would you like to me edit my question so you can see what screen I do see? If you guys don't recognize anything I'll just have to experiment....

Comment: Yes add in that text. There should be a textview in there somewhere :)

Comment: And if none of this works, the only other place that string would be overwritten is in the Java code.

Comment: Don't confuse our new friend @cricket_007 :D

Comment: He's gotta learn how to dynamically update Views at some point. ;)

Comment: Okay I did what you said....found the textview added the reference like every other person has said...and it still runs the same. Just spits out "Hello World."

Comment: So cricket_007 any idea where in the Java code it might be? The Studio pretty much built the app for me so I have no clue....

Comment: Did you rebuild the application? Did it update in the display screen? Did you ensure to do case sensitive @string/Hello_World?

Comment: @Jordan Seanor Yes I did check the casings and rebuilt and ran the app three times.

Comment: @cricket_007: I've looked over the project and found something that might be a clue....while on the tablet I'm testing on it will only show Hello World despite following your instructions. In the design view of content_main.xml (Where you see the phone in the picture) It does show the text of the string value I added in text view.....Does this give anyone any clues?

Comment: @dpolaristar I would just recommend uninstalling the app from your tablet, recompiling, and re-running/installing the program. If it is updating in design view then it appears as if something funky is happening on your app installation.

Comment: @Jordan Seanor tried that too. I think it has something to do with my tablet since I decide to go on with part 2 of the tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78576/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-2

And when I get to the part that involves more code to the MainActivity.Java class when I run my tablet it will go "I'm sorry but OMG Android has stopped running." This happens after I once again uninstall and try again. If the problem IS my tablet or my connection to it, does that mean that my problem is now beyond the scope of this question?

Comment: @Jordan Seanor I should point out the tutorial has at some points deviated from what I have seen on my own screen so it might be outdated and I often improvise/Ask around the internet like I´m doing now.

Comment: @dpolaristar unfortunately it sounds like much more is going on than just setting text. Without debugging your whole code it doesn't seem likely to find a resolution. If you can see it in the desgin view then more than likely you have a setText() somewhere in your java code.

Comment: @Jordan Seanor :I didn't have a setText until I followed more if the tutorial in part 2. Which if its part of the tutorial I would expect it to work. Maybe the tutorial is garbage but I would expect it to not be since its working with everyone else. But yeah when I removed setText like you said. It went back to saying Hello World on Tablet but my string value in Studios....

I'm gonna be frank I have no clue what is going on other then I followed the instructions of part 1 of the tutorial  and have been trying to follow part 2 and part 2s instructions have been causing MORE problems.

Comment: Just a thought? Maybe I should search/ask a new question about my tablet not showing what is shown in design view of the studios? Maybe my problems are beyond the scope of this question. I'm asking because I don't want to get in trouble for what might be seen as posting the same question twice since they are the same problem.

Comment: Good news everyone question was solved.....I somehow changed some kind of configuration by accident which threw it out of wack. I deleted and redid and the project and it suddenly worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Although, the tutorial in the link has plenty of info, it is not well organized/structured.

In order to show a "Hello World!" text, you should paste this in the xml of your activity (MainActivity - maybe) :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

If you really want to use "Hello World!" as a string resource just add in strings.xml

```
<string name="text_4_my_hello_world_example">Hello World!</string>
```

And change in the code above the following

```
android:text="@string/text_4_my_hello_world_example"
```

Good luck and have fun learning!

Answer (score 1):

Because in your layout file, TextView's text attribute must be like this:

```
android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

If you create a new string in strings.xml:

```
<string name="my_string">My Beautiful String</string>
```

And call it in your TextView:

```
<TextView
 ...
 android:text="@string/my_string"
 ... />
```

This should work.

Comment: This is assuming OP did not follow the tutorial and made a completely new string. The tutorial says to change the `hello_world` string.

Comment: Indeed I followed the tutorial verbatim (except I test on a tablet rather then an emulator.)