# Tablet and Android Studios don't match each other's output

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, tablet, galaxy-tab

This question is an offshoot of another question I asked here:
[How to print message in an Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210742/how-to-print-message-in-an-android-app)

However I feel the problems I face are beyond the scope of the original question. In the original question I was asking how to get my Android App to print what I want to a screen and I was using a Tablet I was testing. The problem is in the design view of Android studio's it prints the string value that I want it too, but when I test on the tablet itself it simply print's "Hello World."

I believe the problem is either A...some connection/compatibility issue between the studios or my tablet.

Or B where my Android studios is out of date/the tutorial I was using is out of date. Tutorial can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1#comments

So I'm wondering if someone here can point out a compatibility issue with my tablet. Previous question I linked to in the beginning shows my code and our discussions on that. My tablet is a SM-T350 model shown here:
http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/SM-T350NZAAXAR

I'm not sure what version of Android studios I have but when I start it, it says an update for the studios IS available. If there is a way to check what version I have by release number I'd appreciate that information.

EDIT: my main_content.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/main_textview"
         android:text="@string/textview"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                       />

       </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: My MainActivity.java

```
     package com.example.dpolaristar.omgandroid;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
     import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
          TextView mainTextView;
          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          // 1. Access the TextView defined in layout XML
          // and then set its text
          //mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
          //mainTextView.setText("Set in Java!");
          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

          FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

EDIT: My activity_main.xml file.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.co/tools" 

      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout   

      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"   
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"    
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton  
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"          
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you installed your application to the 
Tablet AFTER changing the string value ? I was targeting more than 30 different devices and never experienced any problem of "incompatibility"

Comment: @Lucius Hipan: Multiple times. I've uninstalled and and then reinstalled it multiple times. All I know is in Android studios when I click design view I see my string being outputted. (Dpolaristar is programming in Android.) But when I run it on tablet it just goes....Hello World as if I never added the string value in the first place. I've rebuilt the project in the studio more times then I can count.

Comment: Try to do File---> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: Please post your layout XML, strings XML, and main java files.

Comment: @Lucius Hipan : It didn't work. And I honestly didn't think it would. I've been at this for almost a week and have started and restarted the computer and thus Android Studios multiple times.

Comment: @dpolaristar please, post relevant codes in your question

Comment: This is likely an issue with your code, not your hardware. Please post your layout XML, strings.xml, and the java code of the Activity you are trying to run.

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle :All of that was posted in the question I linked at the beginning. If what you mean is the activity_main.xml and what not.

Comment: You posted your strings.xml, but I do not see the layout content_main.xml, or your mainActivity.java.  So we don't even know, for example, if you have called setContentView method properly. Please post all your XML layout files, and mainActivity,java on this question.

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle done.

Comment: i cannot see you editted the textview content in the MainActivity class. You wanted it to edit the TextView or something else?

Comment: Please rephrase sentence. you can or cannot? I did make a change but then when it didn't work commented it out. So it runs like it did before I touched it.

Comment: Never mind problem was solved in a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the code of 'main_content.xml', while in your activity you are using the 'activity_main'

Take a look at the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Do you include the 'main_content.xml' into your 'activity_main.xml'?

Comment: I believe I did in the activity_main.xml file I have a line that reads:

              <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Comment: What happens when you try to change the text programmatically?

These 2 lines uncommented:
`//mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
          //mainTextView.setText("Set in Java!");`

Comment: Also, do you have different strings.xml for different screens/devices?
Did you try to install the app on another device or emulator?

Comment: :When I run the commented lines my device says sorry OMG Android (The Name of my App) has stopped running.

No I do not have different strings.xml I only have one tablet to test on and I can't use the built in Emulator that comes with Android studios because my computers processor is not compatible with the driver software it needs. (It needs Intel processor and my laptop uses an AMD)

Comment: You can use third party emulators, like genymotion.

Do you get any logs with that error?

Comment: What do you mean "logs" where would I find such logs. And it's not really a error I see in Android studios it just says on my Tablet that my App has stopped running. (Unless I comment out the two offending lines.) I put said offending lines due to following second part of an online tutorial so I don't think me following a tutorials instructions should break the app.

Comment: The app stopped running due to the crash, and it crashed due to an error in your code. <br>
"Logs" is simply a lot of text about application work, including errors. Connect your device over usb and open "Android Monitor" tab in Android Studio. Then launch your application using Android Studio (not adb directly) and get that error in logs.

Comment: Did it when I ran it, I looked at the logs and didn't see any errors pop up in the logs.